# How to make applying filters to multiple objects less laggy in fabric js?

Tags: fabricjs

i have about 10 objects that filters can be applied to, and a filter engine that goes through them one by one and applies filters to each.

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric'

const filters = {
  brightness: new fabric.Image.filters.Brightness(),
  premade: new fabric.Image.filters.ColorMatrix(),
}
const addFilter = (canvas, index, value = null) => {

  let pickedFilter
  let objects = canvas.getObjects()
  

  switch (index) {
    case 1:
      pickedFilter = sepia
      break;
    case 8:
      pickedFilter = brightness
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
  
  objects.forEach((o) => {
    if (o.filters) {
      if (!o.filters[0]) {
        o.filters.push(filters.brightness)
        o.filters.push(filters.premade)
      }
      pickedFilter(o, value)
    }
  });
  canvas.renderAll();
}

export default addFilter

  function sepia(o){

    let value = [
      0.67,     0,     0,     0,     0,
      0,     0.54,     0,     0,     0,
      0,     0,     0.4,     0,     0,
      0,     0,     0,    1,     0
    ]
    delete filters.contrast.contrast
    delete filters.premade.matrix
    filters.premade.matrix = value
    o.applyFilters()
  
  }
function brightness(o, value) {
  
  value = (value / 100) / 2
    filters.brightness.brightness = value
    o.applyFilters()
  
}
```

initally when objects don't have filter at filters[0], i go ahead and push the filters.

later on when the user moves the slider like in [this gif](https://i.imgur.com/DABihSf.gif), i go through each object and if it can have filters i go ahead and change the value of filter and then apply the filters. as you can see it's a bit laggy and i think the biggest problem is that there are multiple objects that filters are applied to.

in this gif, i get rid of all objects but one and i can feel that the performance is better, but the problem is that i need to apply the filters to all of the objects.

i tried running the code inside filter functions only once (for example i put the value asignment, deletion of previous value and value asignment inside sepia funtion, outside the loop), but it didn't change anything.

how can i improve the performance and make it less laggy?

Comment: a gif and a piece of code aren't useful. Please create a working snippet in stack overflow

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi https://codepen.io/musabii/pen/JjNOwPm this represents my problem well. make sure to open it in full page view, because it doesn't show the images otherwise for me. thanks in advance.